# How i can display all category group name?

Tags: ee2, categories, category-group

I want to display category group name in detail page of articles is it possible and how i can do this ?

Comment: Can you please add some additional information about your setup, your templates and what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write simple SQL for it:

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT group_id, group_name FROM exp_category_groups WHERE site_id='1'"}
    <p>
        Category Group ID: {group_id}
        Category Group Name: {group_name}
    </p>
{/exp:query}
```